# TensorFlow.js Find the main idea of the text with

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js, summary

I installed TensorFlow.js library with cdn. Then I wrote a code to give the main idea of my sentence and tried to print the main idea on the console, but there was nothing on the console, so I gave it to the console on separate lines .log and it keeps printing "d". he doesn't read anything after that. Here's the code:

html:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/universal-sentence-encoder@latest"></script>
```

JavaScript:

```js
const text = document.querySelector('p');

async function konuBul() {

    console.log("d");

    const model = await use.load();

    console.log("c");

    const vektor = model.embed(text.textContent);

    console.log("b");

    const similarTexts = await model.nearestNeighbors(vektor, {numResults: 5});

    console.log("a");

    similarTexts.forEach((similarText) => console.log(similarText.text));

}

konuBul();
```

I used the above codes, but as a result of my research on the internet, I used a different version of this code and there was the same problem. I want the sentence to find its main idea. In short, the problem is not finding the main idea and only printing "d" on the console.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your async code inside a `try/catch` you will be able to handle any errors happening in your code:

```js
async function konuBul() {

  try {
    console.log("d");
    const model = await use.load();
    console.log("c");
    const vektor = model.embed(text.textContent);
    console.log(model);
    console.log("b");
    const similarTexts = await model.nearestNeighbors(vektor, { numResults: 5 });
    console.log("a");
    similarTexts.forEach((similarText) => console.log(similarText.text));
  } catch(e){
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

If you open your console, you will see that the code is breaking due to the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'textContent') at konuBul`

This is because there is not `text` found in the HTML code.

Even if you add such an element like this:

```html
<p>Some text to be parsed here</p>
```

...your code will still fail due to the following error caused by the method **nearestNEighbors** not found on the model you are using:

`TypeError: model.nearestNeighbors is not a function at konuBul`